# How can I dispose a widget in swt and again create that widget in the same place?

Tags: java, swt

I am developing a `swt` application where I want to dispose a button and again want to recreate that in the same place. But I am getting widget is disposed error. How can I do it?
o

Comment: show us the relevant code, and also the error message with it's stacktrace. Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) example.

Comment: please edit your question, nobody will read code stuffed into a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try alternate paths... that is not disposing a button but just hiding it. If you are using a `GridLayout` you can use [`GridData#exclude`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/GridData.html#exclude) to ensure the button is hidden and its space is utilized by others.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using GridLayout, you can set button invisible invoking `Control:setVisibile(boolean)`.